# LD_PRELOAD does not work and LD_DEBUG shows nothing

Tags: bash, ld

I use `LD_PRELOAD` to overwrite the `read` function. For a minimal test application it works fine, but if I test it with a larger application it does not work anymore. Also `LD_DEBUG=all` does not show anything at all:

```
LD_DEBUG=all LD_PRELOAD=./lib.so ./big_app
```

This just runs `./big_app` and `LD_PRELOAD` has no effect. Is there a way to debug that?

Comment: Regarding LD_PRELOAD, of course you ensured that real and effective user ids are identical ?

Comment: Not sure what's the exact difference:)

But that just made me question things and I see now that it does not work because of `setcap` (which is used on the big application)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This answer is only valid for a GNU/Linux environment.

From comments, OP's binary has privilege features added to it: capabilities. This switchs `ld.so(8)` into *secure-execution mode* which *by default* disables most dynamic-linker related environment variables, including `LD_PRELOAD` and `LD_DEBUG`.

> [Secure-execution mode](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages/ld.so.8#Secure-execution_mode)
>
> For security reasons, if the dynamic linker determines that a binary
> should be run in **secure-execution mode, the effects of some
> environment variables are voided or modified** [...]
>
> A binary is executed in secure-execution mode if [...] including:
>
> - The process's real and effective user IDs differ, or the real and effective group IDs differ. [...]
> - **A process with a non-root user ID executed a binary that conferred capabilities** to the process.
>
> [...]

However, with *root* access on the system it's possible to configure it to meet the prerequisites of *secure-execution mode* for these two parameters when run as non-root, still as described in [`ld.so(8)`](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages/ld.so.8#Secure-execution_mode):

> [`LD_PRELOAD`](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages/ld.so.8#LD_PRELOAD)
>
> [...]
>
> **In secure-execution mode**, preload pathnames containing slashes are
> ignored. Furthermore, **shared objects are preloaded only from the
> standard search directories** and **only if they have set-user-ID mode bit
> enabled (which is not typical).**

What are the standard search directories? They are provided with the output of `ld.so --help`. For example on a Debian amd64/x86_64:

```shell
$ ld.so --help
[...]

Shared library search path:
  (libraries located via /etc/ld.so.cache)
  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu (system search path)
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu (system search path)
  /lib (system search path)
  /usr/lib (system search path)

[...]
```

In the end the shared object file must be in one of these places. From testing it :

- doesn't have to be owned by root, as long as it has mode `u+s` set.
- can be a symlink pointing to the actual `u+s` file in any place as long as the symlink is in the right place.
- no path should be present in `LD_PRELOAD`, only (a) filename(s) without `/` anywhere.
- if the binary's capabilities don't grant it arbitrary access to read a file, the shared object can have its mode set so that it allows only a single user or a group (typically `chmod o-rwx` should be applied and the correct ownership set, then `u+s` restored). For setuid-root or `CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE` / `CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH` this probably won't prevent the library to be used by any user executing such privileged binary.

> [`LD_DEBUG`](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages/ld.so.8#LD_DEBUG)
>
> [...]
> Since glibc 2.3.4, **`LD_DEBUG` is ignored in secure-execution mode,
> unless the file `/etc/suid-debug` exists** (the content of the file is
> irrelevant).

I didn't find a way to restrict it to only an user or group.

Example (with root access using `sudo`):

```shell
$ sudo touch /etc/suid-debug
$ sudo cp -aiL ./lib.so /usr/lib/lib.so
$ sudo chmod u+s /usr/lib/lib.so
```

which now allows to run as normal user with both variables taken into account:

```shell
LD_DEBUG=all LD_PRELOAD=lib.so ./big_app
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the very detailed and helpful explanations

Answer (score 2):

You should check whether your executable is statically built or not. If it is, LD env variables won't have any effect.

You can check that with `ldd`, a utility that will show you shared object dependencies.

If your executable is static, it should print something like:

```
ldd ./big_app
not a dynamic executable
```

Comment: Also wonder what it would do with a dynamically linked a.out binary.

Comment: There is no "a.out" binary format AFAIK: `a.out` is just the default *filename* when the C compiler produces a binary.

Comment: @U.Windl See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A.out

Comment: I stand corrected.